# Galaxy S6 Edge clock issue

Tags: crashes, clock, samsung-galaxy-s-6-edge+

I just bought S6 edge and it seems there is a problem with clock. When I go to clock app to set the alarm it is just blank and I can't set anything. Thankfully I can set the alarm I need using the Google now. Then I tried setting the scheduled Do not disturb mode. When I click on the Start time or End time fields it says "Setting stopped working". I am not sure how to fix it. I tried few tricks and finally I had to do Factory reset, but that didn't solve my issue either. Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Here are the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running a custom ROM and you haven't modified the phone in any way, and a factory reset did not help, you should hand it in if it's still under warranty. This kind of behavior after a factory reset could be caused by a hardware issue.

If you are out of support, you might want to try rooting your phone to check if this behavior goes away on other roms.